# Javascript testing: Passing around Jasmine 2.0's "done" function - not what I expected

Tags: javascript, testing, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm relatively new to asynchronous testing, and the following behavior surprised me. What am I missing?I'd appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction

If this works [Coffeescript]:

```
# Works
describe "Asynchronous specs", ->
    o = {}    
    beforeEach (done) ->        
        o.async = ->
            console.log "Finished"

        spyOn o, "async"
        setTimeout (->
            o.async()
            done()
        ), 1500

    it "async executed", ->        
        expect o.async
            .toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Why doesn't passing the `done()` function as a parameter also work?

```
# doesnt work: Test times out
describe "Asynchronous specs", ->
    o = {}    
    beforeEach (done) ->        
        o.async = (passedDone)->
            passedDone()
            console.log "Finished"

        spyOn o, "async"
        setTimeout (=>
            o.async done
        ), 1500

    it "async executed", ->        
        expect o.async
            .toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` method will never be called in the second example because it is spied on. You can change

```
spyOn o, "async"
```

to

```
spyOn(o, "async").and.callThrough()
```

so the method is spied and also all calls are delegated to the `async` method.